# Rails - Add serialize Array to existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add an array to my model "User"

```
serialize :year, Array
```

How do I add this attribute to my model? I see most places saying to just write this into the Users.rb file, but then there is never a column. Am I missing something?

Also, How do I access it from my controller? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the column `year` to database as `text` column

```
add_column :users, :year, :text
```

You can access it like normal array.

Eg:

```
user = User.new(:year => ["2012", "8", "22"])

user.year #=> ["2012", "8", "22"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have a column in your database. Then serialize the object and no need to mention the type  of the object, if you are not sure. It is as follows :

```
    serialize :year
```

If you assign hash it will be hash object or you assign array it will be Array object.